# Java Spring Security Запись атрибутов в сессию при авторизации

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Какой метод интерфеса (ну и какой интерфейс) отвечает за запись роли и данных в сессию. Предполагаю что можно его переопределить и добавить при логине, в зависимости от роли записывать необходимые атрибуты.
Есть вариант переопределить контроллер "/j_spring_security_check", но опять же нужно добавить туда всю логику по авторизации ... это было бы странно.
Наверняка есть уже стандартные решению, я не смог найти.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете написать свой вариант **UserDetailsService**

```
@Service(value = "authService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User name: " + username);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

и хранить нужные вам атрибуты в модели. Сервис подключается вот так

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // настройка безопасности
    }

    @Resource(name="authService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Предположим, что ваша модель называется **User**, тогда в контроллере вы можете использовать

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if(principal instanceof User) {
    ((User) principal).getPhone(); // взять что-то из модели
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил это в лоб. Поставил настройку http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true), а вот уже в контроллере на "/", закидываю необходимые атрибуты в сессию. В таком случае получается что если юзер залогинен, атрибуты у него точно должны быть т.к. этот контроллер не обойти при логине. Но понимаю что это не верно, есть наверняка решение правильное, чтоб при логине забрасывало на нужную страницу и атрибуты тоже были в сессии.

Comment: не надо добавлять в ответы других людей свои вопросы. для подобных целей есть комментарии.